# mod_rewrite rule include shortcode exclude actual pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to build a URL shortener and need to have any incoming links for domain.com/azAZ09 forward to page.php?code=azAZ09  while ignoring any legitimate pages that end in .php in root and ignore any requests for sub-directory contents

Unfortunately, I appear to just be stabbing in the dark. any chance someone could at least point me to a clear and understandable tutorial or help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind. found a good cheat sheet  [here](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/mod_rewrite_cheat_sheet.pdf)

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)?$ index.php?sc=$1 [L]